# Help identify symbol of vintage biplane seaplane wing

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane, seaplane, biplane

I recently bought a "Vintage" biplane seaplane model from an Etsy shop. The images on the listing didn't include an unobstructed view of the top of the wings. When I received it, I found that it had symbols displayed on each end of the top wing. The symbol (attached) looks like an X with curved tips and a diamond in the center. My search so far has only returned similar listings for similar models, but I have been unable to locate the aircraft type or the origin of the symbol. My main concern is the origin of the symbol. Any help would be really appreciated!

[image: Image of model airplane from the original listing]

[image: Image of the symbol from a similar listing]

Comment: It's highly likely that this is "art", and as such may be completely unrelated to any actual aircraft...

Comment: Explain why this has to do with aviation. It could be simple art.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke, it is aviation art. Asking whether it represents an actual airplane is not off topic. Merry Christmas!

Comment: The float-plane formerly known as Twitter ?

Comment: Strong pirate vibe, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol is unlikely to represent anything outside the builder's imagination, because so much of the rest of the airplane is unrealistic.

- The outboard struts are canted inwards, not outwards.  (The upper wing is almost never "shorter" than the lower one, for many reasons.)
- The inboard struts are between the wings, instead of being cabane struts.
- The strutwork between floats and tail is overbuilt.
- The floats are almost as big as the wings.
- Tail floats are [exceedingly rare](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80141/why-do-tail-dragging-seaplanes-not-exist#80142).

The symbol *might* be hinting at the [rounded cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luftstreitkr%C3%A4fte) used by German airplanes in 1914-15, without being too obviously German.  But only the builder knows for sure.

All that being said, the design is undeniably cute, rather like a puppy with big feet, so I'd say the builder has succeeded in what they were aiming for.

Comment: The float struts cannot take shear and - if that were a real plane - will fall off in an attempt to land on water.